# Is this scenario possible with Vuforia User Defined Target?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mobile, vuforia

I am trying to store the Vuforia User Image targets locally so users will not have to create the targets every time they leave the scene.

I tried to store the variables to create the new image target in a static class so i can retrieve them when i am back to the scene. and create the image targets then add them to the dataset.

```
 //****************************************************************************************************
    //Trying to load image target between scenes
    //****************************************************************************************************
    //Deactivate the dataset in order to add the image target
    m_ObjectTracker.DeactivateDataSet(m_UDT_DataSet);

    var LastImageTrackable = ImageTargetStorage.newTrackable;

    if(LastImageTrackable != null)
    {

        //Find UDT behavior and Gameobject
        ImageTargetBehaviour imageTargetCopy = Instantiate(ImageTargetTemplate);
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        int RandomNum = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
        imageTargetCopy.gameObject.name = "UserDefinedTarget-" + RandomNum;

        // Add the target to the dataset
        try{
            m_UDT_DataSet.CreateTrackable(LastImageTrackable, imageTargetCopy.gameObject);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("An Error has occured while trying to create image target from different scene.");
        }


        // Activate the dataset again
        m_ObjectTracker.ActivateDataSet(m_UDT_DataSet);
    }
    //****************************************************************************************************
```

Unity Crashes and never give me any useful data on the issue. 
the step that causes the crash is

```
m_UDT_DataSet.CreateTrackable(LastImageTrackable, imageTargetCopy.gameObject);
```

which gets the LastImageTrackable from previous creation. 
Please advise me on this error and kindly suggest a different framework if Vuforia is not suitable for this simple task.

Comment: You don’t seem to store the new data. You indeed store them in the dataset for usage but you don’t store for next round. You could convert the LastInsgeTrackable to txt file and save it.

Comment: I am initializing it as static values which should be global while the project is still on. Notice the condition, only if LastImageTrackable is not null.

Comment: I am not sure if i can store it as a text. Many values are private and unaccessible.